# How can I covert a list view mode to display an Add mode?

Tags: list-form, custom-list

I have a Sharepoint custom list. I want to use it as a registration form. This means the list needs to be displayed in an "Add item" mode? How can this be done? I am assuming with loading the list in Infopath 2010 and editing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the NewItem form for the list. When you create a SharePoint list, you get a NewForm, an EditForm, and a DispForm (display) for "free".

M.

Answer (score 0):

Custom lists usually have a toolbar on top of them, but if this is a custom view of list created via Data View Web Part here is a [tutorial](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-sharepoint-list-toolbar-to-a-data-view-HA010244828.aspx) to restore Add item back. You just need to enable toolbar on such a view.

Answer (score 0):

use this url:
http://yoursite/Lists/yourlist/NewForm.aspx

This will automatically give you a form where you can add a new entry to your custom list.

This form url can also be found by the object model if you are working programatically: [SPList.DefaultNewFormUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.defaultnewformurl.aspx) (MSDN)